# how to calculate the model accuracy manually?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, confusion-matrix, multiclass-classification

I have a a confusion matrix and a classification report as shown in the attached image.
My question is, how this accuracy is calculated?
I have tried many formula to calculate the accuracy by hand but no one give me the right one?

please, I need a help to find how the model is calculate this accuracy?
What is the mathematical equation that he used to reach this accuracy?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzPIR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide the total number of correct answers by your total sample size. In this case:

- class 0: 918 * 0.9434... = 866 correct predictions
- class 1: 2522 * 0.9964... = 2513
- class 2: 349 * 0.9198... = 321
- (866 + 2513 + 321) / 3789 = 0.9765...